# VB.NET - Single string to List

Tags: string, vb.net, list

I have the following code:

```
Program.RaygunClient.SendInBackground( ex, New List(Of String)() From {"tag"} )
```

Is there a more succinct way to do this in VB.NET? For instance, this looks shorter and more descriptive:

```
Program.RaygunClient.SendInBackground( ex, "tag".ToList() )
```

But (obviously) does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: The second code snippet should be `Program.RaygunClient.SendInBackground( ex, {"tag"}.ToList() )`, i.e. calling `ToList` on a literal array.

Comment: That said, maybe your `SendInBackground` method would be better written with that second parameter being a `ParamArray`.  That way you could just pass as many or as few individual `Strings` as you like or a single `String` array.

Comment: You could also write an extension method for the `String` class that would enable you to actually call `ToString` on a single `String` object.

Comment: Unfortunately, the library is 3rd party. So I can't make it a `ParamArray`. But the extension method isn't a bad idea

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the compiler is happy with:

```
Program.RaygunClient.SendInBackground(ex, {"caught"})
```

Comment: What is the data type of that second parameter? From your description, I assumed that it was `List(Of String)` but, if it accepts a `String` array as well, I would think that it must be `IEnumerable(Of String)`, `ICollection(Of String)`, `IList(Of String)` or the non-generic version of one of those interfaces.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It is `IList(Of String)`, not `List(Of String)` like I had indicated. I'm assuming the compiler is being smart and accepting `{"caught"}` as a literal `List` instead of a literal array?

Comment: There's no such thing as a literal `List`.  `{"caught"}` is an array and all arrays implement the `IList(Of T)` interface, so a `String` array implements `IList(Of String)`.